# How to increment a value within a subdocument of a document in mongodb with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, database

I would like to increment the quantity of a element within a subdocument of a document found in the database.

My find on the document works:

```
Cart.findOne({_id: '2JKD6eynaYmTGnbiZ',"items.productId": 'inkGTN7T89fqwEqTB' });
```

returning this:

```
{ _id: '2JKD6eynaYmTGnbiZ',

  items: 

   [ { _id: 'LYKPShnDDfYHS8zmx',

       productId: 'inkGTN7T89fqwEqTB',

       quantity: 1 } ],

  sessionId: 'jhizTjhiErYRNKhJW’ }
```

But I can't seem to increment the `qty` of an element within the items sub document with this update:

```
Cart.update({
    _id: '2JKD6eynaYmTGnbiZ’, "items.productId": ‘inkGTN7T89fqwEqTB'
}, {
    $set: {
        updatedAt: new Date()
    },
    $inc: {
        "items.quantity": 10
    }
});
```

I dont know if I am referencing it wrong, I have tried to use `items.$.productId` to refer to the element but won't even return the document on the find.

Comment: I think all you need to call is $set on the new field and updated field, and add  { upsert: true }, I am not sure what $inc does.  see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) that represents the index of the matched `items` array element in your `$inc`:

```
Cart.update(
{
    _id: '2JKD6eynaYmTGnbiZ', "items.productId": 'inkGTN7T89fqwEqTB'
}, {
    $set: {
        updatedAt: new Date()
    },
    $inc: {
        "items.$.quantity": 10
    }
});
```